# How to add link to the product name in Woocommerce breadcrumb

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, breadcrumbs

For styling pruposes, I'm trying to add a link to the product name in the Woocommerce breadcrumb. Since it don't have a link and I'm trying to add a style to all "a" tags in the breadcrumb, it displays different as you can see in the next image:

[Woocommerce Breadcrumb](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J2PKe.jpg)

I only need it to have a link, even with 'href="#"'. Where and how can I add this link?

Answer (score 0):

Can you post your code so we can better understand your situation?

EDIT: based on your given code. you can put the product name in a div and give it a custom id and then use css to make it uppercase.

```
<head>
    <style>
    #product {
      display: inline;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

     <nav class="woocommerce-breadcrumb" itemprop="breadcrumb">
         <a href="manolitas.com/site">Collections</a> &gt;
         <a href="manolitas.com/site/product-category/around-the-world/… the World">Category</a>
         &gt;<div id = "product"> Ines </div>&gt;
         <a href="#" class="wbsectitle3">Shop</a>
     </nav>
     <script src="javascriptfilepath/javascriptfilename.js">
     </script>
 </body>
```

Then you can add a click event with javascript to add a link to the div element.
JAVASCRIPT

```
var product = document.getElementById("product");
product.onclick = function(){
window.location.href = "http://www.whereveryouwannago.com";
};
```

Comment: I just install Woocommerce in Wordpress and that's how it comes. The only code is a custom CSS to give the required style (extra padding, color and text transformation) to the links inside the breadcrumb:

.woocommerce .woocommerce-breadcrumb a {
    color: #777;
    padding: 25px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
}

Comment: You can add a unique id to the product link and then style that unique id with css.
    `<a href="#" id="product">Product</a> 
#product { padding: 25px; text-transform:uppercase;}`

Comment: The issue is that there's no link on the product name. This is the source code of the breadcrumb (the product name is "Ines"):
<nav class="woocommerce-breadcrumb" itemprop="breadcrumb">
<a href="/site">Collections</a> &gt; <a href="/product-category/around-the-world/">Around the World</a> &gt; Ines &gt; <a href="#" class="wbsectitle3">Shop</a>
</nav>

Comment: I only need it to have a link, even with 'href="#"'. Where and how can I add this link?

Comment: i've updated my answer with code to add a link to the product name in the breadcrumbs and make the text uppercase